# Dividing an image into subparts using keras

Tags: python, image, keras, lambda, layer

I'd like to do an implementation of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324166730_Face_Tracking_with_Convolutional_Neural_Network_Heat-Map).

To do this I would like to divide an image into a 64x64 sub-square area as shown in this picture.(for example an image of size 256x256 will be divided into 16 parts of size 64x64.)
[image]

I am already able to do this as a step in my pre-processing but I would like this work to be done at the inference time .
I've done some research and it seems that it is possible to do this using a lambda layer. However, I am still unable to realize this.
I must confess that I'm still having trouble understanding how all this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `tf.image.extract_patches` function.

```
out = Lambda(
    lambda x: tf.split(
        tf.image.extract_patches(x, [1,16,16,1], [1,16,16,1], [1,1,1,1], padding="VALID"),
        256, axis=3)
    )(inp)
```

This will produce `256` (i.e. `16 x 16`) , `[batch_size, 16, 16, 3]` patches.

**PS**: However, I think you can achieve this using data processing pipeline as well. There shouldn't be anything stopping you from using the data processing pipeline during inference, that you used for training.

Comment: it seems that's what I needed, I'll edit my question once I finalize this work.

Thank you